# CLOB to Zip file

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, clob

I have CLOB column in Oracle DB which contains XML files.

How can I create single zip file which will contain all xml files from clob column?

Only one row is there in table which has this CLOB column with xmls

Comment: In the database that you are working in, is APEX installed? If so, you can use the `APEX_ZIP` package: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/aeapi/ADD_FILE-Procedure-2.html#GUID-C079D220-7C17-4EB8-8D57-B7D2B77DB974

Comment: @EJEgyed Don't think it will work xml files are there in single CLOB column i just want to create zip file of that CLOB column (it is only one row)
select ENTITY From FILES_STORE; (Return only one row but CLOB has 10xml)
Here content of ENTITY column are xml file . ENTITY column is CLOB type

Comment: You've tagged this as both `python` and `plsql`, which language are you wanting to implement this in?

Comment: @eduffy anyone will suffice if you know how to do it using Python that will also help.

Answer (score 3):

You can leverage the `APEX_ZIP` package to query your `CLOB` column(s) and add them all to a zip file that will be stored in a `BLOB`. You can then do whatever you need with that `BLOB`.

```sql
DECLARE
    l_temp_blob      BLOB;
    l_dest_offset    INTEGER := 1;
    l_src_offset     INTEGER := 1;
    l_lang_context   INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_LANG_CTX;
    l_warning        INTEGER;
    l_zip            BLOB;
    l_file_counter   PLS_INTEGER := 1;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (SELECT entity
                FROM TB_INDEXFILES_STORE
               --Add whatever where clause you want here
               WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
    LOOP
        DBMS_LOB.CreateTemporary (lob_loc => l_temp_blob, cache => TRUE);

        DBMS_LOB.ConvertToBlob (dest_lob       => l_temp_blob,
                                src_clob       => i.entity,
                                amount         => LENGTH (i.entity),
                                dest_offset    => l_dest_offset,
                                src_offset     => l_src_offset,
                                blob_csid      => DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_CSID,
                                lang_context   => l_lang_context,
                                warning        => l_warning);

        apex_zip.add_file (p_zipped_blob   => l_zip,
                           p_file_name     => 'file' || l_file_counter || '.xml',
                           p_content       => l_temp_blob);
                           
        l_file_counter := l_file_counter + 1;
    END LOOP;

    apex_zip.finish (l_zip);
    
    --Do whatever you want with your l_zip blob which is the zip file
END;
/
```